# How to read a CSV line with "?

Tags: python, csv

A trivial CSV line could be spitted using string split function. But some lines could have `"`, e.g.

```
"good,morning", 100, 300, "1998,5,3"
```

thus directly using string split would not solve the problem.

My solution is to first split out the line using `,` and then combining the strings with `"` at then begin or end of the string.

What's the best practice for this problem?

I am interested if there's a Python or F# code snippet for this.

**EDIT:** I am more interested in the implementation detail, rather than using a library.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's a [csv](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html) module in Python, which handles this.

**Edit**: This task falls into "build a lexer" category. The standard way to do such tasks is to build a state machine (or use a lexer library/framework that will do it for you.)

The state machine for this task would probably only need two states:

- Initial one, where it  reads every character except comma and newline as part of field (exception: leading and trailing spaces) , comma as the field separator, newline as record separator. When it encounters an opening quote it goes into
- read-quoted-field state, where every character (including comma & newline) excluding quote is treated as part of field, a quote not followed by a quote means end of read-quoted-field (back to initial state), a quote followed by a quote is treated as a single quote (escaped quote).

By the way, your concatenating solution will break on `"Field1","Field2"` or `"Field1"",""Field2"`.

Comment: Like with most parsing problems, it's a more sustainable practice to use a library if one exists.  If the OP is really interested in the implementation, I'm sure the Python library is open source.

Comment: As we say in the Python community: "Use the source, Luke".  It's totally open and already installed with Python.  Just read it.

Answer (score 3):

From [python's CSV module](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html#csv-examples):

reading a normal CSV file:

```
import csv
reader = csv.reader(open("some.csv", "rb"))
for row in reader:
    print row
```

Reading a file with an alternate format:

```
import csv
reader = csv.reader(open("passwd", "rb"), delimiter=':', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
for row in reader:
    print row
```

There are some [nice usage examples in LinuxJournal.com](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/handling-csv-files-python).

If you're interested with the details, read "[split string at commas respecting quotes when string not in csv format](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2009-March/1198663.html)" showing some nice regexen related to this problem, or simply read the csv module source.

Answer (score 2):

The generic implementation detail would be something like this (untested)

```
def csvline2fields(line):
    fields = []
    quote = None
    while line.strip():
        line = line.strip()
        if line[0] in ("'", '"'):
            # Find the next quote:
            end = line.find(line[0])
            fields.append(line[1:end])
            # Find the beginning of the next field
            next = line.find(SEPARATOR)
            if next == -1:
                break
            line = line[next+1:]
            continue
        # find the next separator:
        next = line.find(SEPARATOR)
        fields.append(line[0:next])
        line = line[next+1:]
```

Comment: Actually, the recommendation to look at the CSV module in the Python open source is way better. Silly me.

Answer (score 1):

*Chapter 4 of The Practice of Programming* gave both C and C++ implementations of the CSV parser.