# How do I split a line by commas, but ignore commas within quotes

Tags: python, csv

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [How to read a CSV line with "?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139750/how-to-read-a-csv-line-with)

I have seen a number of related questions but none have directly addressed what I am trying to do.
I am reading in lines of text from a CSV file.

All the items are in quotes and some have additional commas within the quotes.
I would like to split the line along commas, but ignore the commas within quotes.
Is there a way to do this within Python that does not require a number of regex statements.

An example is:

```
"114111","Planes,Trains,and Automobiles","50","BOOK"
```

which I would like parsed into 4 separate variables of values:

```
"114111"  "Planes,Trains,and Automobiles"  "50" "Book"
```

Is there a simple option in `line.split()` that I am missing ?

Comment: use the csv module

Comment: @GregHewgill (and three others): Not really a duplicate. The other question is specifically more interested in the implementation detail, rather than using a library.

Comment: "I am reading in lines of text from a CSV file." Then your question is really "How do I parse a CSV file?" Ask the question you really want answered. It often saves both you and potential answerers a lot of time.

Comment: I felt my question was a little more detailed than simply 'how do I parse a csv file'. There are simple csv files where the split() method would suffice.

Comment: @chrisfs, ...CSV is a (moderately) well-defined format. That definition includes quotes protecting commas within them from being split points (and being able to represent literal quotes by doubling them within a quoted string). Anyone who calls splitting on commas _without_ taking quotes into account "parsing a CSV" is wrong.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

If you want to read lines from a CSV file, use Python's [`csv` module](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/csv.html?highlight=csv#csv) from the standard library, which will handle the quoted comma separated values.

### Example

```
# cat test.py
import csv
with open('some.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        print(row)
```

```
# cat some.csv
"114111","Planes,Trains,and Automobiles","50","BOOK"
```

```
# python test.py

['114111', 'Planes,Trains,and Automobiles', '50', 'BOOK']
[]
```

Answer (score -7):

You can probably split on "," that is "[quote][comma][quote]"

the other option is coming up with an escape character, so if somebody wants to embed a comma in the string they do \c and if they want a backslash they do \\.  Then you have to split the string, then unescape it before processing.