# Conditional regular expression to split on commas

Tags: python, regex

I am splitting a string in python and my goal is to split by commas except these between quotations marks. I am using

```
fields = line.strip().split(",")
```

but some strings are like the following one:

> 10,20,"Installations, machines",3,5

How can I use regular expressions for accomplishing this?

Comment: Feel free to debate and find a suitable duplicate target if available. Keep comments constructive and related to the post and not choices of individuals.

Comment: Why do you *want* to use regular expressions for accomplishing this? The `csv` module does it for you, see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/7682561/3001761

Comment: Seriously, does it have to be regex?  It's much more complex than everyone expects, and Python's `csv` module is just sitting there, waiting to be used.  Have you tried it?

Comment: @jonrsharpe and Alan Moore, I believed csv just split as I did, I am going to have a look to the module then. Thanks

Comment: @jonrsharpe and Alan Moore, you are right, csv gives correct stuff. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I agree that regular expressions may not be the best tool for the job, I found the problem quite interesting on its own.

```
import re
split_on_commas = re.compile(r'[^,]*".*"[^,]*|[^,]+|(?<=,)|^(?=,)').findall
```

This regexp consists in four alternative parts in this order:

1. any number of non-commas, followed by a substring enclosed between double quotes, followed by any number of non-commas;
2. at least one non-comma;
3. an empty substring following a comma;
4. an empty substring at the start of the string, and followed by a comma.

Some tests:

```
assert split_on_commas('10,20,"aaa, bbb",3,5') == ['10', '20', '"aaa, bbb"', '3', '5']
assert split_on_commas('10,,20,"aaa, bbb",3,5') == ['10', '', '20', '"aaa, bbb"', '3', '5']
assert split_on_commas('10,,,20,"aaa, bbb",3,5') == ['10', '', '', '20', '"aaa, bbb"', '3', '5']
assert split_on_commas(',10,20,"aaa, bbb",3,5') == ['', '10', '20', '"aaa, bbb"', '3', '5']
assert split_on_commas('10,20,"aaa, bbb",3,5,') == ['10', '20', '"aaa, bbb"', '3', '5', '']
assert split_on_commas('10,20,"aaa, bbb" ccc,3,5') == ['10', '20', '"aaa, bbb" ccc', '3', '5']
assert split_on_commas('10,20,ccc "aaa, bbb",3,5') == ['10', '20', 'ccc "aaa, bbb"', '3', '5']
assert split_on_commas('10,20,"aaa, bbb" "ccc",3,5,') == ['10', '20', '"aaa, bbb" "ccc"', '3', '5', '']
assert split_on_commas('10,20,"aaa, bbb" "ccc, ddd",3,5,') == ['10', '20', '"aaa, bbb" "ccc, ddd"', '3', '5', '']
assert split_on_commas('10,20,"aaa, "bbb",3,5') == ['10', '20', '"aaa, "bbb"', '3', '5']
assert split_on_commas('10,20,"",3,5') == ['10', '20', '""', '3', '5']
assert split_on_commas('10,20,",",3,5') == ['10', '20', '","', '3', '5']
assert split_on_commas(',,,') == ['', '', '', '']
assert split_on_commas('') == []
assert split_on_commas(',') == ['', '']
assert split_on_commas('","') == ['","']
assert split_on_commas('",') == ['"', '']
assert split_on_commas(',"') == ['', '"']
assert split_on_commas('"') == ['"']
```

#### Update: comparison with the `csv` module solution

Similar questions have been asked many times on SO, and each time the best / accepted answer was "Just use the `csv` module". Perhaps it's useful to point out some differences between the recommended solution and my `re` proposition. But first, devise a `csv` function with the same interface as `split` (not idiomatic, but consistent with the original requirement):

```
import csv
split_on_commas = lambda s: csv.reader([s]).next()
```

The first thing to be aware of is that `csv.reader` does more than a smart `split`. The external delimiters are suppressed:

```
assert split_on_commas('10,20,"aaa, bbb",3,5') == ['10', '20', 'aaa, bbb', '3', '5']
```

Which can lead to some strange behaviours:

```
assert split_on_commas('10,20,"aaa, bbb" ccc,3,5') == ['10', '20', 'aaa, bbb ccc', '3', '5']
assert split_on_commas('10,20,aaa", bbb ccc",3,5') == ['10', '20', 'aaa"', ' bbb ccc"', '3', '5']
```

I am sure this is not a problem with a generated CSV, since the offending double quotes would be escaped.

More shocking is the fact that [this module still does not support Unicode](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html):

```
split_on_commas(u'10,20,"Juan, Chô",3,5')

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnicodeEncodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-83-a0ef82b5fc26> in <module>()
----> 1 split_on_commas(u'10,20,"Juan, Chô",3,5')

<ipython-input-81-18a2b4070348> in <lambda>(s)
      1 if __name__ == "__main__":
      2     import csv
----> 3     split_on_commas = lambda s: csv.reader([s]).next()
      4 
      5     assert split_on_commas('10,20,"aaa, bbb",3,5') == ['10', '20', 'aaa, bbb', '3', '5']

UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xf4' in position 15: ordinal not in range(128)
```

But there is of course a third difference: my solution has not be thoroughly tested, and is *not* guaranteed to work in the cases I didn't think of... Now, since this approach seems to have several real use cases (*e.g.*, non-TSV files, non-ASCII input), I would be glad if some regex guru, far from dismissing it as dangerous, could help to find out its limitations and improve it.

Comment: this is really nice! I was thinking on "match this stuff unless that other stuff". I am going to study your regex, it is going to be very helpful to me. Thanks!! Far beyond cvs.

Comment: Thanks. Please beware that I may have forgotten some edge cases. More testing is needed. Anyway, last time I checked the csv module, it didn't support Unicode input, which was a deal breaker for me.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I'd do it:

```
import re

data = "my string \"string is nice\" other string "
print re.findall(r'(\w+|".*?")', data)
```

**The output will be:**

```
['my', 'string', '"string is nice"', 'other', 'string']
```

I don't think there's anything to explain here as the regex speaks for itself. Anyway, if you have any doubts I recommend [regex101](https://regex101.com/)

**\w+** - match any word character `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`
**"** - matches the characters `"` literally
**.*?** - matches any character (except newline)

If you also want to get rid of the square brackets, do this:

```
import re

string = "my string \"string is nice\" other string "
parsed_string = re.findall(r'(\w+|".*?")', string)

print(", ".join(parsed_string))
```

**The output will be:**

```
my, string, "string is nice", other, string
```

Answer (score 0):

As jonrsharpe and Alan Moore mentioned, the Python's built-in [CSV module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) would be a much better solution.

As per their own example:

```
import csv
with open('some.csv', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        print row
```

Answer (score -1):

Regular expressions will not work well here.

You can split by comma and then recombine...
Or use the csv module as suggested in the comments...

```
line = '10,20,"Installations, machines",3,5'
fields = line.strip().split(",")

result = []
tmpfield = ''
for checkfield in fields:
    tmpfield = checkfield if tmpfield=='' else tmpfield +','+ checkfield
    if tmpfield.strip().startswith('"'):
        if tmpfield.strip().endswith('"'):
            result.append(tmpfield)
            tmpfield = ''
    else:
        result.append(tmpfield)
        tmpfield = ''

if tmpfield<>'':
    result.append(tmpfield)

print(result)
```