# Regular expression python ignore pattern between quotes

Tags: python, regex

I am splinting a text based on ",". I need to ignore the commas in text between quotes (simple or doubled).

Example of text:

```
Capacitors,3,"C2,C7-C8",100nF,,
Capacitors,3,'C2,C7-C8',100nF,,
```

Have to return

```
['Capacitors','3','C2,C7-C8','100nF','','']
```

How to say this (ignore between quotes) in regular expressions? (of python)

For now, I am using

```
pattern = re.compile('\s*,\s*')
pattern.split(myText)
```

Comment: Capacitors,3,"C2,C7-C8",100nF,,Capacitors,3,'C2,C7-C8',100nF,,

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I split a line by commas, but ignore commas within quotes Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7682561/how-do-i-split-a-line-by-commas-but-ignore-commas-within-quotes-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use regex for this. With a little tweaking, you can use `csv` module to parse the line perfectly (`csv` is designed to handle quoted commas). Just normalize the quotes to double quotes:

```
import csv

s = """Capacitors,3,"C2,C7-C8",100nF,, Capacitors,3,'C2,C7-C8',100nF,,"""

print(next(csv.reader([s.replace("'",'"')])))
```

result:

```
['Capacitors', '3', 'C2,C7-C8', '100nF', '', ' Capacitors', '3', 'C2,C7-C8', '100nF', '', '']
```

Comment: I started to have some issues using `csv.reader` between Python2.7 and Python3 also using different CSV format ,as \t-separeted or ;-separeted. Because this I chosen regex, but appear be more easy to solve this compatibility first?

Comment: Thank @Jean, I merged your tips with the regex that I was using and the `dialect.delimiter` that I already knew.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you changed your question. That looks like a csv-formatted file:

```
import io

s = """\
Capacitors,3,"C2,C7-C8",100nF,,
Capacitors,3,'C2,C7-C8',100nF,,"""

[i for i in csv.reader(io.StringIO(s), delimiter=',', quotechar='"')]
```

Returns:

```
[['Capacitors', '3', 'C2,C7-C8', '100nF', '', ''],
 ['Capacitors', '3', "'C2", "C7-C8'", '100nF', '', '']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Since question is tagged under regex so here is regex version :

```
s="""Capacitors,3,"C2,C7-C8",100nF,,
Capacitors,3,'C2,C7-C8',100nF,,"""
import re
pattern=r"(([\"'])(?:(?!\2).)*|[^,\n]+)"
word_list=[]
match=re.finditer(pattern,s)
for find in match:
    word_list.append(find.group())

print(word_list)
```