# Script to compare a string in two different files

Tags: python, perl, bash

I am brand new to stackoverflow and to scripting. I was looking for help to get started in a script, not necessarily looking for someone to write it.

Here's what I have:
File1.csv - contains some information, I am only interested in MAC addresses.
File2.csv - has some different information, but also contains MAC address.

I need a script that parses the MAC addresses from file1.csv and logs a report if **any** MAC address shows up in file2.csv.

The questions:

1. Any tips on the language I use, preferably perl, python or bash?
2. Can anyone suggest some structure for the logic needed (even if just in psuedo-code)?

## update

Using @Adam Wagner's approach, I am really close!

```
import csv
#Need to strip out NUL values from .csv file to make python happy
class FilteredFile(file):
        def next(self):
                return file.next(self).replace('\x00','').replace('\xff\xfe','')

reader = csv.reader(FilteredFile('wifi_clients.csv', 'rb'), delimiter=',', quotechar='|')
s1 = set(rec[0] for rec in reader)

inventory = csv.reader(FilteredFile('inventory.csv','rb'),delimiter=',')
s2 = set(rec[6] for rec in inventory)

shared_items = s1.intersection(s2)
print shared_items
```

This always outputs:(even if I doctor the .csv files to have matching MAC addresses)

> set([])

Contents of the csv files

> wifi_clients.csv
>
> > macNames, First time seen, Last time seen,Power, # packets, BSSID, Probed ESSIDs
>
> inventory.csv
>
> > Name,Manufacturer,Device Type,Model,Serial Number,IP Address,MAC Address,...

Comment: In what format are the MAC addresses?

Comment: Do you know the column the mac address is in in both files?

Comment: Can you please post some sample data?

Comment: There's [Text::CSV_XS](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Text::CSV_XS) and [Regexp::Common::net](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Regexp::Common::net) for perl.

Comment: Btw, did you mean "if a MAC address **from file1.csv** shows up in file2.csv", or did you actually mean **any MAC address**? I am assuming the former, but it never hurts to be specific.

Comment: I've edited the post with sample structure of the .csv files. @TLP I meant, "any" good catch!

Comment: There's a world of difference, so you should probably emphasize that in your question.

Comment: @awhitehatter Perhaps you need to trim your mac-addresses of additional whitespace, or otherwise normalize them... I just tested your code on two made up files (one row each) "123,a,d" and "a,b,c,d,e,f,123" and it printed `set(['123'])`.  It it looks to have worked to me.

Comment: Thanks for all of your help Adam; I will give that a shot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's the approach I'd take:

1. Iterate over each csv file (python has a handy `csv` module for accomplishing this), capturing the mac-address and placing it in a set (one per file).  And once again, python has a great builtin `set` type.  [Here's a good example of using the `csv` module](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2139776/331473) and of-course, [the docs](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html#module-contents).
2. Next, you can get the `intersection` of set1 (file1) and set2 (file2).  This will show you mac-addresses that exist in both files one and two.

Example (in python):

```
s1 = set([1,2,3])  # You can add things incrementally with "s1.add(value)"
s2 = set([2,3,4])

shared_items = s1.intersection(s2)
print shared_items
```

Which outputs:

```
set([2, 3])
```

Logging these shared items could be done with anything from printing (then redirecting output to a file), to using the `logging` module, to saving directly to a file.

I'm not sure how in-depth of an answer you were looking for, but this should get you started.

**Update: CSV/Set usage example**

Assuming you have a file "foo.csv", that looks something like this:

```
bob,123,127.0.0.1,mac-address-1
fred,124,127.0.0.1,mac-address-2
```

The simplest way to build the set, would be something like this:

```
import csv

set1 = set()
for record in csv.reader(open('foo.csv', 'rb')):
    user, machine_id, ip_address, mac_address = record
    set1.add(mac_address)
    # or simply "set1.add(record[3])", if you don't need the other fields.
```

Obviously, you'd need something like this for each file, so you may want to put this in a function to make life easier.

Finally, if you want to go the less-verbose-but-cooler-python-way, you could also build the set like this:

```
csvfile = csv.reader(open('foo.csv', 'rb'))
set1 = set(rec[3] for rec in csvfile)   # Assuming mac-address is the 4th column.
```

Comment: Thanks, I have my script now reading the first file and doing a simple print screen of all fields. I had to write a filter, to replace NUL bytes. Anyway, being new to python, I'm not sure how to actually assign the MAC address fields to a set. It looks like I could use Dictreader class of the cvs module to get the MAC Address fields, but I have not figured out how to pipe those into a set. Thoughts?

Comment: @awhitehatter, you could use Dictreader, but it's probably overkill here.  Either way, I've updated my post with a quick example on how to do this with one file (you can adapt for the second).

Comment: thanks, I updated my script before I saw this! I will give this a try!

Answer (score 1):

I strongly recommend python to do this.

'Cause you didn't give the structure of the csv file, I can only show a framework:

```
def get_MAC_from_file1():
    ... parse the file to get MAC
    return a_MAC_list
def get_MAC_from_file2():
    ... parse the file to get MAC
    return a_MAC_list
def log_MACs():
    MAC_list1, MAC_list2 = get_MAC_from_file1(), get_MAC_from_file2()
    for a_MAC in MAC_list1:
        if a_MAC in MAC_list2:
            ...write your logs
```

if the data set is large, use a dict or set instead of the list and the intersect operation. But as it's MAC address, I guess your dataset is not that large. So keeping the script easy to read is the most important thing.

Answer (score 1):

Awk is perfect for this

```
{
   mac = $1  # assuming the mac addresses are in the first column
   do_grep = "grep " mac " otherfilename" # we'll use grep to check if the mac address is in the other file
   do_grep | getline mac_in_other_file  # pipe the output of the grep command into a new variable
   close(do_grep)  # close the pipe
   if(mac_in_other_file != ""){     # if grep found the mac address in the other file
     print mac > "naughty_macs.log"  # append the mac address to the log file
   }
}
```

Then you'd run that on the first file:
`awk -f logging_script.awk mac_list.txt`

(this code is untested and I'm not the greatest awk hacker, but it should give the general idea)

Comment: btw, if you have bash, you probably have awk installed also

Comment: I thought about AWK, I'll consider looking into this a little deeper! thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For the example purpose generate 2 files that that look like yours.

File1:

```
for i in `seq 100`; do 
   echo -e "user$i\tmachine$i\t192.168.0.$i\tmac$i"; 
done > file1.csv
```

File2 (contains random entries of "mac addresses" numbered from 1-200)

```
for j in `seq 100`; do 
    i=$(($RANDOM % 200)) ; 
    echo -e "mac$i\tmachine$i\tuser$i"; 
done > file2.csv
```

Simplest approach would be to use join command and do a join on the appropriate field. This approach has the advantage that fields from both files would be available in the output.

Based on the example files above, the command would look like this:

```
join -1 4 -2 1 <(sort -k4 file1.csv)  <(sort -k1 file2.csv)
```

join needs the input to be sorted by the field you are matching, that's why the sort is there (-k tells which column to use)
The command above matches rows from file1.csv with rows from file2.csv if column 4 in the first file is equal with column 1 from the second file.

If you only need specific fields, you can specify the output format to the join command:

```
join -1 4 -2 1 -o1.4 1.2 <(sort -k4 file1.csv)  <(sort -k1 file2.csv)
```

This would print only the mac address and the machine field from the first file.

If you only need a list of matching mac addresses, you can use uniq or sort -u. Since the join output will be sorted by mac, uniq is faster. But if you need a unique list of another field, sort -u is better.

If you only need the mac addresses that match, grep can accept patterns from a file, and you can use cut to extract only the forth field.

```
fgrep -f<(cut -f4 file1.csv) file2.csv
```

The above would list all the lines in file2.csv that contain a mac address from file1
Note that I'm using fgrep which doesn't do pattern matching. Also, if file1 is big, this may be slower than the first approach. Also, it assumes that the mac is present only in the field1 of file2 and the other fields don't contain mac addresses. 
If you only need the mac, you can either use -o option on fgrep but there are grep variants that don't have it, or you can pipe the output trough cut and then sort -u

```
fgrep -f<(cut -f4 file1.csv) file2.csv | cut -f1 | sort -u
```

This would be the bash way.

Python and awk hints have been shown above, I will take a stab at perl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;

open F1, $ARGV[0];
my %searched_mac_addresses = map {chomp; (split /\t/)[3] => 1 } <F1>;
close F1;

open F2, $ARGV[1];

while (<F2>) {
    print if $searched_mac_addresses{(split "\t")[0]}
}

close F2
```

First you create a dictionary containing all the mac addresses from the first file:

```
my %searched_mac_addresses = map {chomp; (split /\t/)[3] => 1 } <F1>;
```

- reads all the lines from the file1
- chomp removes the end of line
- split splits the line based on tab, you can use a more complex regexp if needed
- () around split force an array context
- [3] selects the forth field
- map runs a piece of code for all elements of the  array
- => generates a dictionary (hash in perl's terminology) element instead of an array

Then you read line by line the second file, and check if the mac exists in the above dictionary:

```
while (<F2>) {
    print if $searched_mac_addresses{(split "\t")[0]}
}
```

- while () will read the file F2, and put each line in the $_ variable
- print without any parameters prints the default variable $_
- if can postfix a instruction
- dictionary elements can be accessed via {}
- split by default splits the $_ default variable